# change icon at row in data-table with out affect other icon at each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have fa-square-o up the table
and I used while loop to fill data-table from data-base 
in one column I have two icons of font awesome one is fa-star-o and another is fa-square-o.
I use jQuery to change icon on click.
When i click in on icon is working probably but the other icon has same class in other row is hidden.

This is HTML Code for square upper table

```
<li class="dropdown li-inv-h">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
     <i class=" i-invo"><span class="caret"></span></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Nothing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Is reading</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Not reading</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-o" ></i></a>
</li>
```

This is PHP Code for column has Font Awesome in side While loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
echo ' <tr>
<td class="col-lg-1">
   <span><i class="fa fa-square-o sqr" id="'.$row["id"].'"></i></span>
   <span class="fa-m-inv"><i class="fa fa-star-o str" id="'.$row["id"].'"></i></span>
</td>
<td class="col-lg-1">'.$row["name"].'</td>
</tr>
```

My java-script is

```
$('.sqr').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("fa-square-o")) {
        $("i.fa-square-o").removeClass("fa-square-o");
        $(this).addClass("fa-check-square-o");
        $(this).css({'color':'blue'});
    }else{
        $("i.fa-square-o").removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
        $(this).addClass("fa-square-o");
        $(this).css({'color':'black'});
    }
});
$('.str').click(function(){
        //var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
        $("i.fa-star-o").removeClass("fa-star-o");
        $(this).addClass("fa-star");
        $(this).css({'color':'yellow'});
    }else{
        $("i.fa-star-o").removeClass("fa-star");
        $(this).addClass("fa-star-o");
        $(this).css({'color':'black'});
    }
});
```

T

```js
$('.sqr').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa-square-o")) {
   $("i.fa-square-o").removeClass("fa-square-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-check-square-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'blue'});
  }else{
   $("i.fa-square-o").removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-square-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'black'});
  }
 });
 $('.str').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
   $("i.fa-star-o").removeClass("fa-star-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-star");
   $(this).css({'color':'red'});
  }else{
   $("i.fa-star-o").removeClass("fa-star");
   $(this).addClass("fa-star-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'black'});
  }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown li-inv-h">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class=" i-invo"><span class="caret"></span></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Checked</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Unchecked</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Unreading</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-o" ></i></a>
</li>
<table id="data-table" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>User</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem for me not in php code but in java-script via font-icon change, When i click in one icon in row all other icon in other row is effective. that mean i have one empty star in each row when i click this star is remove from this row and com other star fill by yellow color but in my code when i click star all other star in each row is remove also.

I want Fix this problem, also i want when any class has fa-check-square-o change fa-icon upper table to fa-minus-square and add id of row to array to make one event choice like delete.

I read more post and not found post nearly this

Thank you every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$("i.fa-star-o").removeClass("fa-star-o");` To

`$(this).removeClass("fa-star-o");`

```js
$('.sqr').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa-square-o")) {
   $(this).removeClass("fa-square-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-check-square-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'blue'});
  }else{
   $(this).removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-square-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'black'});
  }
 });
 $('.str').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
   $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o");
   $(this).addClass("fa-star");
   $(this).css({'color':'red'});
  }else{
   $(this).removeClass("fa-star");
   $(this).addClass("fa-star-o");
   $(this).css({'color':'black'});
  }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown li-inv-h">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class=" i-invo"><span class="caret"></span></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Checked</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Unchecked</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Unreading</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-o" ></i></a>
</li>
<table id="data-table" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>User</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-1">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o sqr"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o str"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Name4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```